# What's happening with flash banners when resizing website window with responsive design?

Tags: flash, responsive-design, autoresize, banner, banner-ads

I couldn't find a website to see how it works... At the moment I have a website with fixed width and the sidebar is 300px wide, and the flash banners/adverts are going there with fixed size. Usually those banners are with sizes 300px or 250px.

What happenes if I change the design to responsive? And I'm planning to do that. Are they going to be resizing too? How are they handled? If the flash content is 300px wide, how it will look on the responsive sidebar which will vary from let's say 350px to 250px according to the resolution... Can they be resized dynamically too with media queries or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SWFObject** uses the object element in HTML5. The object element allows you to nest alternative  flash content inside of it that is accessible for people without the required Flash Player or JavaScript support. You make it **responsive** of course as here;
Example:-

```
.swfObject
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}



<object>
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/NmRTreaCJXs?version=3"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<embed wmode="transparent" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/NmRTreaCJXs?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" class="swfObject" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</object>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have to use <embed /> tag for the flash object to be with 100% width and height? At the moment here is how my codes look like for Flash banners, and I was always wondering, which way is the best to display flash banners
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/755
I don't know how to paste it here, it says it's too long, so you can see it on the link above

Comment: Just use any height and width according to the requirement. Use 14th one. Further more, take a look on Objects in HTML5 by Mozilla Developer Network. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/object

Comment: So <embed /> tag is not necessary? What is the cleanest and best code to display flash banner?

Comment: All major browsers support object as well as embed tags in HTML5. You can also use some Jquery tools like-http://jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/flashembed/index.html But normal HTML5 tags are preferred today.

Comment: OK but what is normal tag? To use only <object> tag without <embed> tag inside? Or with embed tag inside? Or to use only embed tag? Can you give example of what's best to display flash banner (.swf) without all the unnecessary parameters, and of course the ability to be resizible.

Comment: When you put a Flash movie on a html page, you will have to use EMBED tag inside OBJECT tag. Example here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_flashobject